# Mongodb -Moogose query array fields filter

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I want to filter when agg : 6 and 'value' greater than : 1000  and  agg : 5 and 'value' greater than : 2000
Schema: Posting

```
Query:db.postings.find(
             { agg: { 
                 $elemMatch: {
                     $and:[
                     {agg:'5', value: { $gte: '2000'} },
                     {agg:'6', value: { $gte: '1000'} }
                     ]
                     }
                 }}
            );
```

**result : [] empty**

Collection':

```
{   "_id":1,
    "agg" : [ 
        { "value" : "2014", "agg" : "5"}, 
        {"value" : "2500","agg" : "6"}
    ],
}
{
   _id:2,
    "agg" : [ 
        {  "value" : "2015",  "agg" : "5"}, 
        { "value" : "1000","agg" : "6" }
    ],
}
```

> how i write query correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you want documents where the `agg` array satisfies the following condition:

```
contains a subdocument where agg = "6" and value >= "2000"
AND
contains a subdocument where agg = "5" and value >= "1000"
```

Your query is for documents where the `agg` subarray satisfies the following condition:

```
contains a subdocument where
    agg = "6" and value >= "2000"
    AND
    agg = "5" and value >= "1000"
```

The MongoDB formulation of the correct query is

```
{ 
    "$and" : [ 
            { "agg" : { "$elemMatch" : { "agg" : "5", "value" : { "$gte" : "2000" } } } },
            { "agg" : { "$elemMatch" : { "agg" : "6", "value" : { "$gte" : "1000" } } } }
        ]
}
```

Equivalently with `$all`,

```
{
    "agg" : { 
        "$all" : [ 
            { "$elemMatch" : { "agg" : "5", "value" : { "$gte" : "2000" } } },
            { "$elemMatch" : { "agg" : "6", "value" : { "$gte" : "1000" } } }
        ]
    }
}
```

This query matches both documents, I guess as expected. However, I still have doubts that you're doing what you really intend - are you sure you want the values of `agg.agg` and `agg.value` to be strings and not numbers? For example, the following document matches the query:

```
{
    "_id" : 3,
    "agg" : [
        { "agg" : "5", "value" : "2015" },
        { "agg" : "6", "value" : "potato" }
    ]
}
```

This document does not:

```
{
    "_id" : 4,
    "agg" : [
        { "agg" : "5", "value" : "2015" },
        { "agg" : "6", "value" : 2000 }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your use of `$and` is what's screwing you up. `$and` says "I want all documents that match *both* queries". It doesn't make sense to say I want a document with a value of "5" *and* "6" for `agg` which is what you're saying.

If you want to match *any* documents with the conditions in your query (which would match both documents in that collection), you can simply change `$and` to `$or`